# Laravel + Vue, How to do ->where() in vue-for?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm listing projects and those projects have statuses. First I'm listing the statuses and inside them projects, but this returns all the projects no matter what the status.
With Laravel I could just:

`foreach ($projects->where($project->status_id == $status->id) as $project)`

but how to do that with Vue?

```
<div v-for="status in statuses">
{{ status.title }}
<div v-for="project in projects">
{{ project.title }}
</div>
</div>
```

I also tried

```
<div v-for="status in statuses">
{{ status.title }}
<div v-for="project in filteredprojects">
{{ project.title }}
</div>
</div>

computed:{
   filteredProjects() {
      return this.projects.filter(function(project) {
         return project.status_id == status.id;
      })
   }
},
```

But no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set up a relationship between status and projects (as you should since you're using Laravel), you can load the relationship before it ever gets to the Vue component.

**Controller**

```php
$statuses = Status::where(...your conditions...)->with('projects')->get();

// EDIT: or get all statuses without conditions

$statuses = Status::with('projects')->get();

// EDIT 2: get all statuses with conditional projects

$statuses = Status::with(['projects' => function($query) {
   // add your conditions for projects
   $query->where('completed', 0);
}])->get();
```

**Vue**

```js
<div v-for="status in statuses">
    {{ status.title }}
    <div v-for="project in status.projects">
        {{ project.title }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I explained poorly, sorry about that. First I want to list all the statuses in separate divs and inside those divs I want to list all the projects with the status_id value that matches the id of that status. So I want to fetch all the statuses.

Comment: Now I hava a problem that status.projects returns all projects of that status, when before `public function index() { $projects = Project::where('completed', 0)->orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(ordernumber), ordernumber'))->get(); }` returned only the ones with completed value 0 :/

Comment: Fixed it with `$statuses = Status::with(['projects' => function ($query) {
   $query->where('completed', 0);
  }])->get();`

Comment: Sure, nice job making it work.  I would have accounted for this if I could have seen your original controller method to start with.  I've updated the answer to include this possibility for anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<div v-for="status in statuses">
{{ status.title }}
   <div v-for="project in projects">
       <div v-if="status.id === project.status_id">
          {{ project.title }}
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With a quick try no luck. And wouldn't this still fetch all the projects and create a div for each one but only those with matching project.status_id and status.id would have content (project.title)?

Comment: So what do you expect? You can change div to a span. This will make same as you mentioned in your question.